# unable to use nvidia proprietary driver with nvidia card in multi seat setup

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, multiseat, nvidia-geforce

I have an Ubuntu 15.10 installation with onboard Intel Graphics and an nVidia graphics card that I am trying to setup in a multiseat environment using udev/loginctl.

Although I get the output in the primary intel server (seat0), the other seat (seat-1) with nvidia refuses to start. Relevant config and log files are attached.

I have tried both the nouveau and the nvidia binary drivers. Nouveau driver segfaults and the nvidia driver just refuses to be recognised by the server.

I am following the instructions given here:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiseatTeam/Instructions
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

---

$ ps -aef | grep X

```
root       727   718  0 19:34 tty7     00:00:00 /usr/bin/X -core :1 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

---

$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[    17.672] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    17.672] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    17.672] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    17.672] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.2.2
[    17.672] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    17.672] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    17.672] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    17.672] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    17.673] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    17.673] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    17.673]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 0.0.2
[    17.673]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
[    17.673] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    17.673] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    17.673] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    17.673] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    17.673] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[    17.673] (EE) Device(s) detected, but none match those in the config file.
[    17.673] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[    17.673] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[    17.673] (EE)
```

---

$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0 ==
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : NV44 [GeForce 7100 GS]
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000016Asv00001043sd0000821Fbc03sc00i00
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[    17.673] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    17.673] (EE)
[    17.673] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

---

$ lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV44 [GeForce 7100 GS] (rev a1)
```

---

$ loginctl seat-status

```
n/a
         Devices:
                  ├─/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1
                  │ input:input1 "Power Button"
                  ├─/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5
                  │ input:input5 "Video Bus"
                  ├─/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
                  │ input:input0 "Power Button"
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
                  │ [MASTER] drm:card0
                  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1
                  │ │ [MASTER] drm:card0-LVDS-1
                  │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-VGA-1
                  │   [MASTER] drm:card0-VGA-1
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/renderD128
                  │ drm:renderD128
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/graphics/fb0
                  │ [MASTER] graphics:fb0 "inteldrmfb"
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3
                  │ usb:usb3
                  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/0003:046D:C313.0001/input/input6
                  │ │ input:input6 "BTC USB Multimedia Keyboard"
                  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.1/0003:046D:C313.0002/input/input8
                  │ │ input:input8 "BTC USB Multimedia Keyboard"
                  │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/0003:04CA:0061.0004/input/input11
                  │   input:input11 "PixArt USB Optical Mouse"
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.2/usb5
                  │ usb:usb5
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1
                  │ usb:usb1
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0
                  │ sound:card0 "Intel"
                  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
                  │ │ input:input12 "HDA Intel Rear Mic"
                  │ ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
                  │ │ input:input13 "HDA Intel Line"
                  │ └─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
                  │   input:input14 "HDA Intel Line Out"
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb6
                  │ usb:usb6
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb7
                  │ usb:usb7
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb8
                  │ usb:usb8
                  ├─/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2
                  │ usb:usb2
                  └─/sys/devices/virtual/misc/rfkill
                    misc:rfkill
```

---

$  cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-multiseat.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", KERNEL=="card[0-9]*" TAG+="master-of-seat"

# seat0
TAG=="seat", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/*", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat0", TAG+="seat0"
TAG=="seat", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/*", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat0", TAG+="seat0"

# seat-1
#TAG=="seat", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/*", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat-1", TAG+="seat-1"
TAG=="seat", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/*03:00.0/*", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat-1", TAG+="seat-1"
TAG=="seat", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.1/*", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat-1", TAG+="seat-1"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Remove the seat0 udev rules. All devices without a rule are attached to seat0.

For seat1 create the next udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="pci", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/0000:02:00.0", TAG+="seat", TAG+="master-of-seat", ENV{ID_AUTOSEAT}="1", ENV{ID_SEAT}="seat1"
```

replace /devices/pci0000... with your nvidia card

reboot or trigger udev

Use

```
sudo loginctl attach seat1 /sys/devices/pci0000....
```

to attach your graphic card, keyboard, and mouse to seat1

Create a file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d for the nvidia card:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d$ cat 20-nvidia.conf 
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Seat1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
    Option         "ProbeAllGpus" "FALSE"
    MatchSeat      "seat1"
EndSection
```

Success,

Floris

Comment: For some reason, the nvidia driver/kernel module is not being picked up. The server always starts with the nouveau driver. But it is in the blacklist installed by the nvidia driver.

My card is:  NVIDIA Corporation NV44 [GeForce 7100 GS]

I did:
$ apt-get install nvidia-current

which installed nvidia-304 which is what ubuntu-devices recommends for my hardware.

But lsmod | grep video states:
video                  24576  2 i915,nouveau

Thanks for all your help